# How do I keep headers from being repeated in a python dataframe loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, export-to-csv

**Context:** I have been using Python for about 4 days now so my code is probably filled with backwards ways of getting things done, but it works for the most part.

I am scraping a table that has multiple pages. I have a while loop that keeps checking for a "next" button. If it sees one, it scrapes the new data and adds it to the dataframe.

Once it cant find the Next button anymore, it saves the data to a csv.

**My issue:** For every new page it scrapes, it saves the headers again to the csv.

How do I prevent this from happening? This is the last part I have to figure out. Other than that, the output is perfect.

Thank you for the help!

```
while True:
docketnumbers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr/td[1]')
intakedates = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr/td[2]')
custodystatuses = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr/td[3]')
inmatenames = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr/td[4]')
inmateages = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr/td[5]')
inmatecharges = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr/td[6]')
bondamounts = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr/td[7]')

arrstlist=[]

for i in range(len(inmatenames)):
    temporary_data={'docket_number' : docketnumbers[i].text,
    'intake' : intakedates[i].text,
    'status' : custodystatuses[i].text,
    'name' : inmatenames[i].text,
    'age' : inmateages[i].text,
    'charge' : inmatecharges[i].text,
    'bond_amount' : bondamounts[i].text}
    arrstlist.append(temporary_data)

df=pd.DataFrame(arrstlist)

df['last']=df['name'].str.split().str[0]
df['first']=df['name'].str.extract('((?<=\s).*(?=\n))')
df['address']=df['name'].str.extract(r'((?<=\n).*)', re.DOTALL)

df = df.replace(r'\n',', ', regex=True)

df.drop(['name'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.insert(0, 'last', df.pop('last'))
df.insert(1, 'first', df.pop('first'))
df.insert(2, 'address', df.pop('address'))



now = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
os.chdir('E:\scrapingtests')

df[~df.duplicated(subset=['last', 'first'])].to_csv(open(now+'_arrstlist.csv', mode='a'), index=False, line_terminator='\n')

try:
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "NEXT")]')))
    element.click()
    print("Page scrape complete. Moving to next page.")

except TimeoutException as ex:
    print("No more pages.")
    driver.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Without the url or the html/xml code, hard to say. the header could be in a <head> or the first <tr> of your table. In which variable your header is scrapped?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pandas DataFrame, you can index/slice the same way you would a list:

```py
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

In [46]: df
Out[46]:
          A         B         C         D
0 -1.470623  0.196656  0.317571 -1.524480
1 -1.080673 -1.599721 -0.675701 -1.031261
2  0.978590 -1.212172 -0.778095  0.880756
3 -1.123553 -0.522231  0.525033  0.268618
4 -0.940221 -1.353484  0.426843 -0.187475
5 -0.970208 -0.672964 -1.469843  0.943285
6  0.059308  0.355553  1.810508 -0.269099
7  0.623593 -0.210883 -0.735174 -1.078876

In [47]: df[1:-1]  # omits the first row
Out[47]:
          A         B         C         D
1 -1.080673 -1.599721 -0.675701 -1.031261
2  0.978590 -1.212172 -0.778095  0.880756
3 -1.123553 -0.522231  0.525033  0.268618
4 -0.940221 -1.353484  0.426843 -0.187475
5 -0.970208 -0.672964 -1.469843  0.943285
6  0.059308  0.355553  1.810508 -0.269099
```